# How to create an ASP Core web app deployment in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2022

I'm attempting to create an Azure Pipeline that deploys an ASP Core web app to an Azure App Service.

I've created the Azure pipeline to build the web app.

The pipeline deployment expects to find a .zip deployment package in the build, so I'm expecting to configure a Publish step to create this.

In VS2022 the only publish option that creates a web deployment is the `Web Server (IIS)` option which requires the details of an IIS server.

So how in VS2022 do I configure a simple web deployment publish step? I don't expect to have to set up IIS to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You should use **dotnet publish** command to do this. For local development use [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) CLI, for Azure Pipeline you should use [DotNetCoreCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) task with 'publish' command option.
Example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops

Answer (score -1):

So if I am not mistaken you question is specific to how in VS2022 you publish.  As long as you have the Azure SDK installed this option should come up when you try to publish a ASP core web app.

You can choose Azure and point it to your app service or if you want VS to publish the artifacts you can choose the 'folder' option and publish to your local file system and if you zip up that folder where it was published you have your .zip deployment package.

[image]